# How do I avoid opportunity attacks as a spell caster? (Without wasting an action on Disengage or multiclassing?)

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, opportunity-attack, sorcerer, defense

I'm used to playing the classes that run up and hit things and am trying to branch out.
I'm building a level nine Sorcerer/Warlock multiclass In D&D 5e from scratch in a **strictly** no homebrew campaign.

What are the best ways to move around without provoking opportunity attacks?
I know that the Disengage action is always an option, but I was wondering if there was a better way; such as spells that I may be overlooking? I'm looking for something that I could cast once and get out of opportunity attacks over a series of rounds like Zephyr Strike; or like Zephyr Strike could be used as a bonus action as to avoid using any Sorcerer points to quicken the spell.

Basic Character build concept: Divine Soul Sorcerer / Great Old One (Chain Pact) Warlock

Comment: Welcome to the site and please take our [tour] to learn more about how things work here. I'm not sure if this is too broad or a list question, but ways to avoid opportunity attacks can be very wide ranging. Do you have a copy of the PHB or the read the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules)? Is there something about opportunity attacks and how they're triggered that you don't understand?

Comment: FYI, I still think this is going to an unbounded list. There are a LOT of ways to avoid OAs. I very much recommend reading the base rules on them and also browsing [the questions here about OAs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e+opportunity-attack).

Comment: @NautArch Assuming this is limited to magic (else why worry about a Sorlock), this is limited to Sorcerer and Warlock spell lists, which themselves are pretty limited compared to the Wizard's list.  I think it's exhaustively answerable on that basis.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Spells/abilities/feats/items. They've said no to multiclass (although they already have multiclassed.) So you're correct in that we've limited the classes. What about other party buffs?